# How to write a query to get concatenated names of riders with the same weight?

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I want to retrieve a table with all Riders of the same Weight from a table named `Rider`, which is defined in this way:

```
CREATE TABLE Rider(
    name VARCHAR(30),
    weight REAL,
    PRIMARY KEY(name)
) ENGINE=innodb;
```

The data in it is:

```
Alan  55
Ana   55
Anne  50
Bill  65
David 60
Julia 55
Peter 65
Stan  60
```

I want a result like this:

```
50 Anne
55 Alan Ana Julia
60 David Stan
65 Bill Peter
```

I can't figure out how to do it. I can only manage to sort them all by weight with:

```
  SELECT weight, name 
    FROM Rider 
GROUP BY weight;
```

All help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat):

```
SELECT weight, GROUP_CONCAT(name SEPARATOR ' ') as name_list
FROM Rider
GROUP BY weight
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out! Good karma to you!